# Connect MySQL to Fullcalendar

Tags: mysql, node.js, fullcalendar, ejs

Good day everyone.

I try to feed resources from MySQL db to FullCalendar app. The example in its official docs uses PHP script and effectively all examples I found here also utilize PHP. I just started learning web development and haven't touched PHP and wonder if it's possible to tell the calendar to fetch data from db using node.js and EJS. Here's what I've accomplished so far (please be empathic and forbearing with my mistakes):

1. In app.js file I put a connection to MySQL, then in GET route it queries data from db and converts it to JSON object (resources).
2. app.js renders scheduler.ejs and I assume that JSON data is stored in resourcesFeed.

**app.js**

```
var express    = require('express'),
    app        = express(),
    PORT       = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    mysql      = require('mysql');  

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// create connector to DB
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'gdp_scheduler'
});

// connect to DB
con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Connection to DB established')
});

app.get('/scheduler', function(req,res){
    // query the DB
    con.query('SELECT id, given_name, level, color FROM resources', 
        function (err, getResources) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // convert to JSON
        resources = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(getResources));
        console.log(resources);
        return resources;
    });

    // render scheduler page
    res.render('scheduler', {resourcesFeed: resources});
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('Server is up on port:' ,PORT);
});
```

**scheduler.ejs**

```
<%- include("partials/header") %>

<div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- Header -->
    <div>
        <h1>GDP Projects Timeline</h1>
    </div>

    <div>

        <div id='calendar'></div>

    </div>

</div>

<%- include("partials/footer") %>
```

3. The scheduler.ejs header has a link to scheduleSetup.js file.
4. In scheduleSetup.js file, I try to make the calendar to fetch resources from resourcesFeed. And it doesn't work.

**scheduleSetup.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    //Initialize calendar
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

        schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source', //hide lices=nc=se warning

        plugins: [ 'resourceTimeline', 'bootstrap', 'interaction' ], //connect plugins to page

        defaultView: 'resourceTimelineMonth', //define timeline view
  
        editable: true, //enable draggable events

        droppable: true, //it allows things to be dropped onto the container

        resourceGroupField: 'level', //grouping

        resources: 
        'resourcesFeed',
        // [
        //     { id: 2, title: 'John', level: 'Personnel', color: null },
        //     { id: 3, title: 'TEST', level: 'Projects', color: 'red' }
        // ],

        resourcesInitiallyExpanded: true, //the way how resources show up

        events: {
                url: '/sources/events.json',
        }, //link to event json file        

        defaultTimedEventDuration: '24:00', //deafult event duration 

        weekNumberCalculation: 'ISO', //first day of week Monday

        resourceAreaWidth: '10%', //resource column width

        resourceLabelText: 'Projects/Personnel', //resource label

        //header layout
        header: {
            left: 'promptProject today prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'resourceTimelineMonth, resourceTimelineYear,'
        },

        //footer
        footer: true,
        footer: {
            left: 'promptPersonnel'
        },

        height: 'auto', //calendar window size (including header and ffoter)

        //text on standard buttons
         buttonText: {
             today: 'Today',
              month: 'Month',
              year: 'Year'
         },

         //create custom buttns
         customButtons: {
            promptProject: {
                text: 'Add project',
                click: function() {
                    var title = prompt('Project name');
                    if (title) {
                        calendar.addResource({
                            title: title,
                            level: "Projects"
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            promptPersonnel: {
                text: 'Add personnel',
                click: function() {
                    var name = prompt('Name');
                    if (name) {
                        calendar.addResource({
                            title: name,
                            level: "Personnel"
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
         }

    });

    calendar.render();

});
```

I try to comprehend the general sequence of how data is transmitted back and forth between backend and client-side, and what methods are used for this, however apparently have no clear picture yet. Any suggestions, tips, and help would be very much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: "wonder if it's possible to tell the calendar to fetch data from db using node.js"...yes of course. Any server-side language could be used. All you have to do is make the code produce JSON in the format specified by fullCalendar. Beyond that, fullCalendar doesn't know or care where it came from.

Comment: In your fullCalendar config you've specified `events: { url: '/sources/events.json', }` ...but this looks like the URL of a static JSON file. You need to make it point to the URL of a GET route which will return event data in JSON format. Same for the resources, if you want to use that feature too.

Comment: So altogether your app should have 3 routes - one which renders the HTML page, one which returns events in JSON format, and one which returns resources in JSON format.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you very much for your reply. If you don't mind I'll keep asking you more specific questions:

Comment: @ADyson 1. The DB query in the app.js file produces JSON in the exact format as it's specified in fullCalendar docs. I've checked it by manually copy-pasting results from a terminal (console.log(resources)) to scheduleSetup.js resources (commented out lines) `[
            { id: 2, title: 'John', level: 'Personnel', color: null },
            { id: 3, title: 'TEST', level: 'Projects', color: 'red' }
           ],` Everything works just fine. Is this correct statement in app.js file: `return resources;` Do I need it for return JSON output?

Comment: @ADyson 2. Yes, you're right. fullCalendar config file has the link to the static events.json file, which I use now for learning purposes. However eventually, both resources and events should be fed from MySQL db. I need to point fullCalendar config to JSON from app.js and that's where I really stuck. You say I need 3 routes: first is render HTML and I assume it's `app.get('/scheduler', function(req,res){
    // query the DB
  ...
     // convert to JSON
    ....
    });

    // render scheduler page
    res.render('scheduler', {resourcesFeed: resources});
});` from app.js. Correct?

Comment: @ADyson 3. But what another two? The app.js produces correct JSON object, but how to make fullCalendar see it and render? Thank you again.

Comment: _"first is render HTML and I assume it's app.get('/scheduler'"_ ... I think what you've done here is create a route which renders some HTML as a view, and passes the resource data as the model. That's fine, you can do that, but it's not a clear separation of concerns.

Comment: The normal way to make the resource data is to deliver it via a separate URL. So you would specify something like `resources: "/resources"` (as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resources-json-feed). And for events you'd write `events: "/events" (as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed). Those would both be routes in EJS which return JSON data instead of HTML.

Comment: P.S. I'm not too familiar with nodeJS but I think `con.query` is asynchronous, so `return resources` in the callback function within that won't actually return the data to the outer function, because it's not being called there - it's being called later after the outer function has already executed. Consult the manual for that function - I'd guess maybe you can use async/await with it, or it might suggest another way to return the data using Promises.

Comment: @ADyson I very much appreciate your patience. I'm not sure if grasped your comment about the separate URL. So the `app.get('/scheduler', function(req,res){}` response method should not only render the "scheduler.ejs" template, but also send resources data in json format to separate URL "/resources"? And then "schedulerSetup.js" script will get this by having `resources: '/resources'?

Comment: @ADyson Here's what I've done in app.js:  `app.get('/scheduler', function(req,res){
    var resources;  // query from DB //  con.query('SELECT id, given_name, level, color FROM resources', function (err, getResources) { if (err) throw err; feedResources(getResources); });  // format in JSON //  function feedResources(resource){ resources = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(resource)); // render scheduler page // res.render('scheduler', {resources: resources}); }; });`

Comment: @ADyson So no this passes JSON objects to scheduler.ejs. However, I wasn't able to make schedulerSetup.js use these objects as a source of resources for fullCalendar. Thank you

Comment: As far as I can see you would need one `app.get` for each route. So 3 in total.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you so much. It works now! I've separated render route `app.get('/scheduler', function(req,res){ res.render('scheduler'); });` and resource feeding route `app.get('/scheduler/resources', function(req,res){ con.query('SELECT id, title, level, color FROM resources', function (err, resources) { if (err) throw err;         console.log(resources); res.json(resources);  }); });` Thank you very much for support!